# How to link cells in Word Document to share the same content

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to create a page of labels with the same content (table with text and image). However I don't want to copy the table to each cell manually. Even worse if I will decide to change the design and would have to update all cells on page.

Is it possible in MS Word without 3rd party extension packages?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the automatic content update by using external text and graphic sources with fields:

- For text: Goto menu `Insert` -> `Quick Parts` -> `Field...`, select
  `IncludeText` and insert the path to your text source file.
- For an image: Goto menu `Insert` -> `Quick Parts` -> `Field...`,
  select `IncludePicture` and insert the path to your picture.

You can also do this manually by pressing `CTRL + F9` inside the document an insert this coding in the grey control field, e.g.: `{ INCLUDEPICTURE  "c:\\folderofimage\\mylabel.jpg"  \* MERGEFORMAT }`

To switch between view and code just press `ALT + F9`.

Do this for the first cell and format it the way you want it.

Then you have to copy & paste it to every other cell **once** and can update all cells with different content by just switching the source files and press `CTRL + A` (= select everything) and `F9` (= update).

Comment: Thank you. I have went with [this tutorial instead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlxKQcktllI)

Comment: You asked about dynamical adjustments for existing layout content. Your linked tutorial does not adress this.